# Connect 8 ohm speaker output to microphone input on another system

Tags: resistors, potentiometer

I see the question was answered in 2013, but in addition, Id like to ask the follow question(s);

I have a significantly stronger speaker (output) than a computer speaker discussed in previous post.  I'd like to bring the speaker output into a microphone input of another pa system.

Will the diagram below suffice, if I up the resistor (R1) to 20k?
I will install a 1k pot-resistor (R2) as advised by Oli Claser in the earlier post.

Is it necessary to include a diode on the "Speaker Out" line, and the "Speaker Ground" line to prevent the circuit interfering with the speaker?  (As the speaker will stay connected).

[image: Diagram]

[image: Speaker]

[image: Passive Direct Box]

Comment: Can you provide the link to the question you mentioned?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/connect-speaker-output-to-microphone-input

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting a speaker output to a *microphone* input, I would be very worried with connecting the ground from the speaker to the microphone. As microphone inputs are very keen to pick up noise and ground loops are among the worst creators of noise, I would rather carry the signal differentially. I'd use a transformer to pick up the signal from the speaker (pins "Line out" and "Line Gnd" in your schematic should be good points for this) and then carry the signal inside a shielded cable to the microphone.

If you need to do this regularly "in the field", there's someting called a "Leem Box" or a "Leem Direct-Box" which might be a helpful component in various situations of this kind.

Comment: We have to build approximately 15 of these units.  Do you mean I should incorporate a transformer with the circuit as indicated above?

Comment: I managed to find a Passive Direct Box (DB01)
So this would be able to do what I need without any additional components / circuit?

Comment: I've never connected speaker output to *microphone* input so I cannot say - but I think that you still need the resistors in your schematic, otherwise the signal may be too strong for the mic input. I can't check now, can you find some datasheet of the leem box? Any comments from others?

Comment: I've added a picture of a Passive Direct Box (DB01),
I see it has options for -0db, -20db and -40db

Comment: Right, and the Ground Lift. That (DB01) might do it in itself, maybe you could buy one and try it out. I for one would be interested to know if it works in your case. With the -40dB setting, it just might. So you would connect the balanced (XLR) end to your microphone input and the unbalanced (hi-z) end across your speaker. And use ground lift, I would imagine. It's been many many years since I was in this kind of business.