# Raspberry Pi with usb audio interface direct connection with an external device mic in / speaker out

Tags: circuit-design

I want to connect raspberry Pi using usb audio adaptor directly to a device mic-in / speaker out.

RPi spk out -> device mic-in, then
device spk out -> RPi mic-in

I have seen simple circuit and suggestion to match level between mic-in and speaker out. ([Connect speaker output to microphone input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/connect-speaker-output-to-microphone-input)).

My question, since the RPi has software to control both channel (speaker out and mic-in) level, is the suggested circuit for line matching necessary? If I want to attenuate signal level going to the external device mic input, I will lower the volume on my RPi spk. And, lower Rpi mic-in level to attenuate external device spk out signal?

Comment: Does the Rpi really has "speaker out" or simply "line out"? There is a difference between the signal levels. Also does the Rpi have simply a "line in" or only "mic in" or is it selectable? The difference between mic and line levels is even larger, in the order of 20dB.

Comment: There is a usb audio adaptor connected to Rpi   https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-External-Headphone-Microphone-Desktops/dp/B01N905VOY/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=ugreen+audio+interface&qid=1607770527&sr=8-2   I assume this type of audio adaptor is speaker out and mic-in